# Count number of subarrays with sum 0 using hash map

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap

we are given an array say{1,-1,1,-1} now we are supposed to return the number of subarrays with sum=0. Now the tutorial that i'm following is using hash maps for this, they have used a prefix sum array which stores the prefix sum of the arr. The prefix arr={1,0,1,0}. Now, for some reason they have used combination formula i.e., nC2= (n*(n-1)/2). I want to know why did they used that formula?? what was its significance?? in c++.

Answer (score 1):

Let prefixSum be the prefix sum of array (arr)

```
prefixSum[i] = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + ... arr[i];
prefixSum[j] = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + ... arr[i] + ... arr[j];
prefixSum[j] - prefixSum[i] = arr[i] + ... arr[j];

if prefixSum[i] = prefixSum[j]
arr[i] + ... arr[j] = 0
```

so the problem reduces to finding number of pairs (i, j) such that prefixSum[i] == prefixSum[j]. This can be done efficiently by counting the frequency of each prefixSum.

If prefixSum P appears f times in the prefixSum array, you can pick any 2 occurrences in the prefixSum array and the sum of elements in array between the 2 occurrences will be zero.

Example

```
arr = [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1];
prefixSum = [-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0];
prefixSumFrequencyTable = {-1: 3, 0, 3};
```

PrefixSum -1 appears at 0, 2, 4 indices. Pick any 2 indices from [0,2,4] and the sum of elements in array between the 2 indices will be zero. Similarly, for PrefixSum 0, pick any of [1,3,5] and the sum of elements in array will be 0.

Number of ways you can pick 2 items from n items is

<sup>n</sup>C<sub>2</sub> = n*(n-1)/2

So the answer would be to iterate over the prefixSumFrequencyTable and add up <sup>n</sup>C<sub>2</sub> of all values.